# Nested Firestore asynchronous listeners in Android

Tags: android, firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore, listeners

So I have Activities documents in several Days collections and I need to combine all of the Activities in a list. I thought I should loop the collections and then loop the Activities and ended up with the code below which I don't know whether it's the best way to combine multiple collections. Even worse I don't know WHEN my list is ready to be used with all the asynchronous calls. 
Any advice? Thanks!

```
db.collection("calendar").get()
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (DocumentSnapshot ds : task.getResult().getDocuments()) {
                        ds.getReference().collection("thingstodo").get()
                                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                                        for (DocumentSnapshot ds : task.getResult().getDocuments()) {
                                            ScheduledItem item = ds.toObject(ScheduledItem.class);
                                            itemsList.add(item);
                                        }

                                    }
                                });

                    }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [get()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query.html#get()) method you're using on [CollectionReference](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/firestore/CollectionReference) (which is a subclass of Query) returns a [Task](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task) that becomes resolved when the document is ready.  Instead of adding a listener to that individual Task, collect all the tasks into a List, and pass that to [Tasks.whenAllComplete()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks.html#whenAllComplete(java.util.Collection%3C?%20extends%20com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task%3C?%3E%3E)) to respond when the entire set is complete.  You can then examine the results of all the tasks there, as needed.

Comment: Thanks for that, Taskmaster! :) but this is too advanced for me. Would you mind pointing out to some example? Thanks

Comment: do you mean by using .get().getResult()? Can I build a task with this QuerySnapshot? What about the nested CollectionReference?

Answer (score 3):

Managed to code what @Doug had suggested. Thanks taskmaster!
This is so much better:

```
db.collection("calendar").get()
    .continueWith(new Continuation<Task<QuerySnapshot>, Task<?>>() {
        @Override
        public Task<?> then(@NonNull Task<Task<QuerySnapshot>> task) throws Exception {
            List<Task<QuerySnapshot>> tasks = new ArrayList<Task<QuerySnapshot>>();
            for (DocumentSnapshot ds : task.getResult().getResult())
                tasks.add(ds.getReference().collection("thingstodo").get());

            return Tasks.whenAllSuccess(tasks);
        }
    })
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Task<?>>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Task<?>> task) {
            List<QuerySnapshot> lists = (ArrayList<QuerySnapshot>)task.getResult().getResult();
            for (QuerySnapshot qs : lists)
                for (DocumentSnapshot ds: qs) {
                    ScheduledItem item = ds.toObject(ScheduledItem.class);
                    //add to list including day
                    itemsList.add(item);

                }

            //list ready to be used!
        }
    });
```